# How do I configure VSCode extensions in NixOS with home-manager

Tags: nix, nixos

I've reviewd vscode definition in home manager repository and came up with the following definition in my nix file:

```
{ config, lib, pkgs, ... }:

{
    programs.vscode = {
        enable = true;
        package = pkgs.vscode;
        extensions = with pkgs.vscode-extensions; [
            bbenoist.Nix
            justusadam.language-haskell
        ];
        userSettings = {
            "terminal.integrated.fontFamily" = "Hack";
        };
    };
}
```

Everything but the extensions work as expected. After executing "nixos-rebuild switch" I can see that the extensions get downloaded. However, when I launch VS Code, I don't see anything installed. I guess I'm missing one piece in this jigsaw, but not sure where exactly.

Comment: because you're using home-manager the command most likely should be `home-manager switch` (not nixos-rebuild), but I guess you had this in the configuration.nix or outside home-manager since you got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried again after a while and looks like this used to be a bug, as now everything works just fine.